# How to check if a string is blank in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I mean a string is blank if it's empty or contains whitespaces only.
For example, `""`, `" "` and `"\n"` are all blank.

In Rails, we have the `.blank?` method.

Is there something similar in Elixir (or in the Phoenix Framework)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[String.trim/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#trim/1) seems to do the trick as of Elixir 1.3.0.

`strip` still works, but it was soft deprecated [in the 1.3.0 release](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.3.0) and it isn't listed in [the String docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#functions).

Comment: Doesn't work for nil like in Rails so a more verbose solution is required.  This will throw error: String.trim(nil)

Answer (score 17):

There is [String.strip/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/String.html#strip/1) which will convert your 3 examples to `""` which you can compare against.

```
iex(4)> String.strip("\n") == ""
true
iex(5)> String.strip("") == ""  
true
iex(6)> String.strip("    ") == ""
true
```

There was an issue about it https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/2707

Comment: What if I want to to do that inside a guard?

Comment: strip has been soft-deprecated in Elixir > 1.3.0.
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.3.0

Comment: @nicooga if you just want to check for empty strings inside guard, try:

`when binary_part(string, 1, -1)`

Comment: @Chris Keele that does not work for any of the cases.

Answer (score 5):

I published a tiny library to do this properly for any data type. It implements identical behaviour as Rails' `blank?` method in Elixir as far as that's possible.

Library is here: https://github.com/samphilipd/blankable

To install, add blankable to your list of dependencies in mix.exs:

```
def deps do
  [{:blankable, "~> 0.0.1"}]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

why not just use pattern matching

```
iex> a = ""
""
iex> b = "b"
"b"
iex> ^b = "b"
"b"
iex> ^a = "your String"
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: ""
iex> ^a = ""
""
```

or better yet check its byte size

```
iex> if byte_size("") == 0 do true else false end
true
iex> if byte_size("a") == 0 do true else false end
false
```

Comment: I only just started learning Elixir, but even as a newbie I find pattern matching to be the idiomatic way.

Comment: Pattern Matching with strings isn't recommended.

Comment: @tblev for single character matching I believe it is okay. It doesn't look like it is recommended for strings of unknown length.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question today. I ended up defining these function:

```
defmodule Hello do 
  def is_blank(nil), do: true
  def is_blank(val) when val == %{}, do: true
  def is_blank(val) when val == [], do: true
  def is_blank(val) when is_binary(val), do: String.trim(val) == ""
  def is_blank(val), do: false
end

import Hello 

is_blank nil 
is_blank [] 
is_blank %{} 
is_blank "" 

is_blank ["A"] 
is_blank %{a: "A"} 
is_blank "A"
```

Comment: the third one will match any map.

Comment: @LowFieldTheory You are absolutely right. I fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in most cases and is very similar to what `is_blank?` in Ruby does.

```
def is_blank?(data), do: (is_nil(data) || Regex.match?(~r/\A\s*\z/, data))
```